# What does 'x, y =' mean in python syntax?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to work my way through http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/python-imaplib-imap-example-with-gmail/ which has the following line:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search and return uids instead
```

Could someone explain this line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least, as of python 2.7.x, the function will unpack a tuple of 2 arguments returned from a function.  If it returns anything **other than 2 arguments in the tuple**, I believe it will throw an error if you try to unpack more than this.  If it returns 3 arguments and you unpack 2, for example, you will get an exception.

For example:

```
def func(a):
    return (a,a+1,a*2)

a,b,c = func(7)
print a,b
```

==> 7 8 # NOTE Values

```
a = func(3)
print a
```

==> (3, 4, 6)  # NOTE: TUPLE

```
a,b = func(9)
print a,b
```

==> Exception - ValueError: too many values to unpack

This may be different in 3.0+.

Comment: Thanks, just for my own info do all python functions have to return tuples by convention?

Comment: Nope.  You can return tuples, lists, numbers, strings, class instances, functions, dictionaries, lions, tigers, bears, etc., and "None" (the default when you don't explicitly return something).  You should know "what" you are getting in the return (i.e. know your API).

Answer (score 7):

It means that the function you have called returns an iterable, and the index `0` of the iterable is assigned to x and the index `1` is assigned to y. This is called `tuple unpacking`.

Eg)

```
>>> def func(a,b):
...     return b,a
... 
>>> a = 5
>>> b = 7
>>> a,b = func(a,b)
>>> a 
7
>>> b
5 
>>> x = func(a,b)
>>> x
(5, 7)
```

**Edit** to show that returning multiple values, they are packed as tuple by default and then unpacked at the other end. Since there is only one variable x here, the tuple is assigned to x.

Simple function for swapping two variables(Just for an example) that answers your question

Comment: Also true for any iterable, not just tuples.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a tuple. It can be any iterable with exactly as many elements as there are variables to assign to. Tuples are probably the most common, probably followed by lists, but it can even be a generator, a string, or a half-exhausted iterator over a 4-element list.

Comment: Thanks - do all python functions have to return tuples?

Comment: @user61629: If you make a function return more than one variable, it is packed and returned as a tuple. Before assigning, if there are multiple variables at the other end, the tuple is unpacked.

Comment: Thank you but now I am confused : Does'nt that conflict with what James Wucher said above: "You can return tuples, lists, numbers, strings, class instances, functions, dictionaries, lions, tigers, bears, etc., and "None" " ?

Comment: @user61629: Yes of course. They are sent as a tuple unless and until the type is specified

Answer (score 1):

The other answer, that "the function you have called returns an iterable" is a good one.  That is what is happening in your specific example.  This is what is called "unpacking" in python.  The following are examples of unpacking and assignment related to your question:

```
>>> a,b = 1,2
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
>>> a,b,c = ['do', 're', 'mi']
>>> a
'do'
>>> b
're'
>>> c
'mi'
>>>
```

This is one of the pretty features of Python syntax.  If I am not mistaken, it is also optimized - i.e. the fastest way to achieve the result.